# HIVE line significance

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am very new to HIVE and have some silly doubts .

Please bear with me to clarify the same .

What is the significance of these lines
"ROW FORMAT DELIMITED"
"FIELDS TERMINATED BY" 
"LINES TERMINATED BY" ?

Answer (score 0):

`ROW FORMAT DELIMITED` means your rows are delimited.

`FIELDS TERMINATED BY` means your row fields are terminated some keywords like `semicolon(;)`, `comma(,)`, `colon(:)`, etc.

If you want to save your row fields into several columns then you can use both statements `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED` and `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` while creating the table using hive.

`LINES TERMINATED BY` : if you want to separate a line by keyword like new line character (`\n`) or any character then you can use this.

For more reading use this [link](https://sites.google.com/site/hadoopandhive/home/how-to-create-table-partition-in-hive)